# Receiving error when using History.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, history.js

I'm implementing [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) into my web application as a workaround for the lack of support for `history.pushState()` in Internet Explorer.

So far, following demos & tutorials I've written the following code:

```
var historyJs = window.History;

historyJs.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () {
     var State = History.getState();
     historyJs.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
});
```

However, I'm getting the following error returned in Internet Explorer 9:

> SCRIPT5007: Object expected
>
> jquery.history.js, line 1 character 3154

[image]

Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: Did you find out what was causing that error?

Comment: @barry No not yet, still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing a reference to jQuery.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```